# How to print conent of a JFrame by printer

Tags: java, printing, jframe

I would like to print the content of a `JFrame/JPanel` by printer how to do it? Could sb give me an example of code? I do not understand official tutorial.

EDIT:
I thought it is clear. I do not want to print it to file then print it manually. I want to use java to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    this.paint(g);
    g.dispose();

    // File to save output Image
    File imageOut = new File("screenshot.png");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", imageOut);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

with this as a JFrame

Comment: That is not printing by printer, this is printing to a file. But thank you for your time.